# How can I use lodash to find the record with the closest timestamp?

Tags: typescript, filter, timestamp, lodash

I am new to lodash and would like to use it to find the index of an object in an dataset that contains the timestamp closest to a given timestamp/x value.

Say I'm given a timestamp of `var timestamp = "2019-01-01 01:01:30"`.

And my dataset looks like this:

```
dataset = [{
    x: "2019-01-01 00:01:38",
    y: 1
  },
  {
    x: "2019-01-01 01:01:39",
    y: 5
  },
  {
    x: "2019-01-01 02:01:40",
    y: 4
  },
  {
    x: "2019-01-01 03:01:41",
    y: 1
  }
]
```

I would like it to return to me either: the index of the dataset which contains the closest timestamp (which in this case is 1, since the timestamp at index 1 is closest)

OR

I would like it to return the y value of the record at the index which contains the closest timestamp/x value (which would be 5). Returning the entire record would work too. Just some way for me to access the y value.

Which lodash method is ideal for achieving this, and how would I go about constructing it?

Something using .filter or .find, perhaps?

```
_.find(dataset, function(item) {
  return ...?
  );
})
```

Thanks so much for your input!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce()` or lodash's `_.reduce()` to iterate the array, and find the difference between the `x`, and `timestamp`. Store the diff, and the `y` value, if it's lower. Destructure the result to get the `y` value.

Calc the `diff` by taking the absolute of the difference between the parsed values.

```js
const timestamp = "2019-01-01 01:01:30"

const dataset = [{"x":"2019-01-01 00:01:38","y":1},{"x":"2019-01-01 01:01:39","y":5},{"x":"2019-01-01 02:01:40","y":4},{"x":"2019-01-01 03:01:41","y":1}]

const [y] = dataset.reduce((r, { x, y }) => {
  const diff = Math.abs(Date.parse(timestamp) - Date.parse(x))

  return diff < r[1] ? [y, diff] : r
}, [null, Infinity])

console.log(y)
```

Comment: Interesting! In this case, does 'r' represent the record, or index basically?

Comment: The accumulator. Read a bit about reduce.

Answer (score 0):

You can find timestamp like this. I assume that timestamps are not on the same day.

```
const currentDate = new Date('2019-01-01 01:01:30');
const currentSeconds = (currentDate.getHours() * 60) + (currentDate.getMinutes() * 60) + currentDate.getSeconds();
const dates = _.map(dataset, set => {
    const date = new Date(set.x);
    if (date.getDate === currentDate.getDate && date.getMonth === currentDate.getMonth && date.getFullYear === date.getFullYear) {
        const setInSeconds = (date.getHours() * 60) + (date.getMinutes() * 60) + date.getSeconds();

        return {
            x: set.x,
            y: set.y,
            difference: Math.abs(setInSeconds - currentSeconds)
        };
    }
});
const closestDate = _.minBy(dates, 'difference');
console.log(closestDate);
```